# Creating DataType from a parameter Type in Spark Java API

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I'm working with Spark 2.3 . I want to create a DataType object from a giving type parameter: for example StringType, IntegerType...

I tried this:

```
String type="StringType" or String type="IntegerType";
DataType dataType=DataType.fromJson(type);
```

I got this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'StringType': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: StringType; line: 1, column: 21]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
```

Can someone please guide me to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that the method is called `fromJson`. Therefore you need to provide a valid json, and simply wrap the type in double quotes like this:

```java
String type="string" // or String type="integer";
DataType dataType=DataType.fromJson("\"" + type + "\"");
```

NB: also, do not add the "Type" suffix or it won't work, just the name of the SparkSQL type, such as `"string"` or `"long"`.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType.scala) for more detail